# How to implement process-global variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Normally using a variable in a .cpp file results in the variable being globally available, like this:

```
.h file:
extern int myGlobal;
void work();

.cpp file:
int myGlobal = 42;
void work(){ myGlobal++; }
```

When the .cpp file is put in a static library and more than one shared library (DLL) or executable links against the static library, each one has its own copy of `myGlobal`. work() would modify its own version of the variable.

My question now: is there a way to get a process-wide unique variable or pointer to that variable? Similar what thread-local storage would be for thread-wide variables. It doesn't have to be platform independent. Bonus points if it works in Win32 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple: make all the DLLs in the process link to a single DLL that exposes the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Either don't statically link to it (stick myGlobal in a DLL), or only link against the static library once (potentially more of a pain in the neck to achieve).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is overkill for a single process, but I've used [shared sections](https://web.archive.org/web/20090304233958/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125677) to achieve something similar to what you describe.

> Every 32-bit DLL (or EXE) is composed of a collection of sections. By convention, each section name begins with a period. (The period is not required.) These sections can have the following attributes: READ, WRITE, SHARED, and EXECUTE.
>
> DLLs that need to share data among different mappings can use the #pragma pre-processor command in the DLL source file to create a shared data section that contains the data to be shared.
>
> ```
> #pragma data_seg(".shared")
> int iSharedVar = 0;
> #pragma data_seg()
> ```
>
> You must also tell the linker that the variables in the section you defined are to be shared by modifying your .DEF file to include a SECTIONS section or by specifying /SECTION:.shared,RWS in your link line. Here's an example SECTIONS section:
>
> ```
> SECTIONS
> .shared   READ WRITE SHARED
> ```

Comment: Since I only need a process-wide variable, shared sections would be too much. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: FYI: The link in this answer is 404

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at Boost.Interprocess, in particular [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) on sharing memory between multiple processes. There you can find how to use this library to create a shared memory space, open one that's already created (actually "open or create"), resize it to your needs and access it. There's a simple example that should get you going quite fast.

Comment: Question says "process-wide", not multiple process. Shared memory within the same process is probably a little bit overkill.

Comment: You're right. But it does work and it's not that difficult to use. So why not ? :)

Comment: Beware: boost::interprocess is full of pitfalls and gotchas.  For example, on some platforms it has a tendency to busy-wait in things like wait conditions.  Make sure you read the boost code you're using.

Comment: I did look at Boost.Interprocess, but since I only need it process-wide, I think the easy solution would be to put the variable in a separate dll. Thanks for the suggestion, though!