# Shared global variable in C++ static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static, global-variables

I have a MS C++ project (let's call it project A) that I am currently compiling as a static library (.lib). It defines a global variable foo. I have two other projects which compile separately (call them B and C, respectively) and each links the shared static library A in. Both B and C are dll's that end up loaded in the same process. I would like to share a single instance of foo from A between B and C in the same process: a singleton. I'm not sure how to accomplish the singleton pattern here with project A since it is statically compiled into B and C separately. If I declare foo as extern in both B and C, I end up with different instances in B and C. Using a standard, simple singleton class pattern with a static getInstance method results in two static foo instantiations.

Is there any way to accomplish this while project A is statically compiled into B and C? Or do I have to make A a DLL?

Comment: *"If I declare foo as extern in both B and C, I end up with different instances in B and C."* - is this really true?

Comment: It seems to be true - it is the behavior I observer when I step through the program while debugging. I see the constructor for foo called twice and the addresses of the extern variables g_Foo are different in the two modules B and C. Should this not be the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement process-global variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669989/how-to-implement-process-global-variable-in-c)

Comment: @Zach - I don't think so. In this instance the variable needs to be cross-process. Just because it's static global in a DLL doesn't mean different process images have the same instance of it. Each image gets its own instance.

Comment: @Ragster, Hmmm, I don't think I was clear in my question then (or maybe I don't completely understand what you're saying). I really only need a single instance for a given process (it does not need to be visible across processes). Or maybe I don't quite grok what you mean by process images... Thanks!

Comment: Right - I misunderstood your original question - you have different projects, which all link into a single executable - i.e. one process. No cross-process access necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to make A a shared DLL, or else define it as extern in B and C and link all three statically.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "link all three statically"? I am currently linking A statically into both B and C and declaring foo extern in B and C, yet I end up with multiple definitions of foo at runtime. I think you are saying I would need to link A and B statically into C (or A and C statically into B), or link A, B, and C statically into another library. Is that accurate? Thanks!

Comment: The last one, except substitute "another library" with "the final executable". Don't link any of the libraries together. Instead, link A, B, and C statically with your final executable. Any symbols from A that are used in B or C should be declared as extern in B and C, but not defined. 

If you link A, B, and C into another shared library, you just have to make sure that this library encapsulates the singleton from A, because if A is linked statically to the executable and the executable accesses A's static data directly, it will get a different copy than the lib.

Answer (score 2):

No - they are not shared.

From Richter's 'Windows via C/C++' (p583):

> When one process maps a DLL image file
>   into its address space space, the
>   system creates instances of the global
>   and static data variable as well.

So, if you need to share a resource between multiple executables you will need to create a shared kernel object of some sort. I would suggest creating a named file mapping, which you can then use to read and write to from the separate processes (with appropriate Mutex exclusion, of course.)

Comment: Your observation is correct in general, but you oversaw an important claim by the OP: "*Both B and C are dll's that end up loaded **in the same process**.*" So with DLL it would be shared.  The issue here is the static linking.

Comment: By the way, the sharing across processes can be easily achieved as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7705793/3723423

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem actualy :

I have A.EXE linked with B.LIB. 
I have C.DLL also linked with B.LIB.

As you can see, these two program are linked with B.LIB

Now, when required, the A.exe go load C.DLL.
After loading, A.EXE and C.DLL each have separated B.LIB for code and data

The problem it is possible to have a B.LIB "fantom" linked with C.DLL to use the already loaded in A.exe?

I think no. It's a limitation from Window. In Linux you can, if I'm remember correctly. That was the regarded by the -fPic option of GCC. But not sure.

The solution to share global/static data stored in B.LIB with A.EXE and C.DLL is to use shared class/interfaces. Your A.EXE send interface to C.DLL with a data/interface pointer to the B.LIB stored in A.EXE.

In other words, if your C.DLL need to set/shared state of a static variable in B.LIB, your A.EXE must initializ C.DLL with the interface to permit data exchange with the B.LIB in A.EXE.

In all case, the B.LIB stored in C.DLL continue to bloat the global program because of the duplicate code from B.LIB in A.EXE and C.DLL

To reduce the global bloating, you must divide your A.LIB in more D.DLL, E.DLL that are loaded by A.EXE and transmited thru interface to your C.DLL

To reduce the bloated code to zero, you must use full independant interface method.