# C++ boost crashes while using locale

Tags: c++, boost, crash, locale

I am trying to use boost library for providing i18 support to my string class.
I am using Microsoft Visual studio compiler VC10 and 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

I am able to compile and link my application with the boost library however my application crashes while invoking boost::locale::to_upper().

Following is the code I wrote.

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>
#include <boost/system/config.hpp>



 String::MakeUpper()()
    {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale loc = gen("");
    std::locale::global(loc);
    std::string str2 = boost::locale::to_upper("001Öä", loc); // application crashes here.
    std::string str3 = boost::locale::to_upper("001Öä"); // This also does not work
    }
```

The crash happens in the following function. this function throws bad cast exception.

```
template<class _Facet> inline
const _Facet& __CRTDECL use_facet(const locale& _Loc)

{   // get facet reference from locale
_BEGIN_LOCK(_LOCK_LOCALE)   // the thread lock, make get atomic
    const locale::facet *_Psave =
        _Facetptr<_Facet>::_Psave;  // static pointer to lazy facet

    size_t _Id = _Facet::id;
    const locale::facet *_Pf = _Loc._Getfacet(_Id);

    if (_Pf != 0)
        ;   // got facet from locale
    else if (_Psave != 0)
        _Pf = _Psave;   // lazy facet already allocated
    else if (_Facet::_Getcat(&_Psave, &_Loc) == (size_t)(-1))

#if _HAS_EXCEPTIONS

        _THROW_NCEE(bad_cast, _EMPTY_ARGUMENT); // lazy disallowed

....
....
....

}
```

Could you please help me out.

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same issue when using a static library build of Boost 1.55 in a Visual Studio 2008 application on Windows 7 64-bit where both the main executable and a couple DLLs all linked to Boost.  I'm not sure if your issue is the same as mine since you didn't mention using DLLs, but that wasn't something I thought was relevant when I first started investigating this.

If you're just interested in the most straight-forward way to fix this, then building Boost as a shared library should do it.  Specifically, I mean setting the `link` property of the b2 command-line to `shared` rather than `static`.

## Explanation

The reason using a static library build has a problem is due to Boost.Locale using [`std::locale::facet`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/facet) objects for doing its text conversion operations like upper-casing and normalizing.  `std::locale::facet` classes are required to have an `id` static member variable whose unique value is assigned by the Standard Library implementation when it is constructed during static initialization.

The problem with this when using a static library is that all executables and DLLs get their own distinct copy of static member variables from a static library, as discussed in [Shared global variable in C++ static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186926/shared-global-variable-in-c-static-library).  When you use `boost::locale::generator::operator()` to generate a locale, it only installs the `std::locale::facet` objects into the locale that have an `id` member variable that is part of the same DLL or executable where that call is contained.

As I said above, the most straight-forward way to fix this is to build Boost as a shared library.  That way there will only be one copy Boost.Locale's static member variables.  Specifically, they'll be in the Boost.Locale DLL.

## Alternative Solution

You can do this with a static library build of Boost by making sure all of `std::locale::facet` objects from all DLLs and the executable using Boost.Locale get installed into the `std::locale` object you're trying to use.

You can use some code like below to do this.  For DLLs, you could call this in `DllMain` when its second parameter `fdwReason` is `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, and for your executable, you could call it in `WinMain` or some other application entry point (if you're using something like MFC or Qt).

```
void setup_global_locale()
{
    const boost::locale::generator generator;
    const std::locale locale = generator.generate( std::locale(), "" );
    std::locale::global( locale );
}
```

The important piece of the code is that it's using the global locale as the base locale each time it's run, and it installs the newly-generated locale as the new global locale.  This is different from what `boost::locale::generator::operator()` will do, since it uses `std::locale::classic` as the base locale, and that one cannot be modified.  By calling this from each DLL and the executable, you'll install each of their `std::locale::facet` objects into the global locale.