# Boost locale compare throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, locale, collation

The following trivial usage of Boost's locale library generates a runtime error:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale loc = gen("");
    std::locale::global(loc);

    std::wstring a=L"Façade", b=L"facade";

    bool eq = std::use_facet<boost::locale::collator<wchar_t>>(loc).compare(
        boost::locale::collator_base::secondary,
        a, b
    ) == 0;

    if (eq) std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The debugger traps the error in collator.hpp here:

```
int compare(level_type level,string_type const &l,string_type const &r) const
{
    ---> return do_compare(level,l.data(),l.data()+l.size(),r.data(),r.data()+r.size());
}
```

The error is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"

I'm on a late 2013 iMac running macOS Sierra version 10.12 with Xcode 8.0 (8A218a) and boost-1.61.0_1. In hopes that maybe I just failed to install ICU with Boost, I just ran this:

```
brew install boost --with-icu4c --cxx11
```

This sample is based on Boost's own documentation:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html

Thoughts? Thank you.

---- EDIT -----

I tried dumping out info about the default locale:

```
std::cout << std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).name() << std::endl;
```

It contained simply "C" and the other attributes were not what I expected. I thus got explicit in my setup:

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen("en_US.UTF-8");
std::locale::global(loc);

std::cout << std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).language() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).country() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).variant() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).encoding() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).utf8() << std::endl;
```

Which output:

```
en_US.UTF-8
en
US

utf-8
1
```

Sadly, this did not help. Also, I noticed that the following code didn't work as expected:

```
const std::string g = "grüßEN";
std::cout << boost::locale::normalize(g, boost::locale::norm_nfc) << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::locale::normalize(g, boost::locale::norm_nfd) << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::locale::normalize(g, boost::locale::norm_nfkc) << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::locale::normalize(g, boost::locale::norm_nfkd) << std::endl;
```

It output all the same strings:

```
grüßEN
grüßEN
grüßEN
grüßEN
```

This seem to suggest there's something screwy with my install of Boost or ICU.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I encountered the same problem.

Comment: No luck. Sorry.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990412/c-boost-crashes-while-using-locale