# Shared global variable in C++ static library: Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dll

This in in C++:

A static library "A" defines a global variable foo.

"B" and "C" are two dynamics libraries both depending on A hence linking (statically) with A.

Then B and C end up loaded in the same process 
(ex: Application loads B and C).

If we are in a windows environment, we will obtain two different instance of foo, one in B and one in C as clearly explained here:

[Shared global variable in C++ static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186926/shared-global-variable-in-c-static-library)

What about a Linux environment.

Context:
We are currently porting a windows project to linux

Comment: If you won't get an answer I guess you can perform a simple test by changing the global variable from 1 library and checking its value from the second library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each library will ship include a copy of A. However, at runtime only one will be used by all the components of the process.

```
// h.h
extern int a;
void b(void);
void c(void);

// a.c
#include "h.h"
int a = 0;

// b.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "h.h"
void b(void)
{
  printf("%i\n", a++);
}

// c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "h.h"
void c(void)
{
  printf("%i\n", a++);
}

//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "h.h"
int main()
{
  b();
  c();
}

#Makefile
main: libxc.so libxb.so
    cc -o main main.c -L. -lxc -lxb
libxb.so:
    cc -fPIC -shared a.c b.c -o libxb.so
libxc.so:
    cc -fPIC -shared a.c c.c -o libxc.so
```

```
$make
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
0
1
```

Symbol table from `libxa.so`:

```
    53: 000000000020098c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 a
```

From `libxc.so`:

```
    53: 000000000020098c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 a
```

The default visibility is `STV_DEFAULT` which according to [LSB](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/gabi4+/ch4.symtab.html):

> **`STV_DEFAULT`**: The visibility of symbols with the `STV_DEFAULT`
>   attribute is as specified by the symbol's binding type. That is,
>   global and weak symbols are visible outside of their
>   defining
>   component (executable file or shared object). Local symbols are
>   hidden, as described below. Global and weak symbols are also
>   preemptable, that is, they may by preempted by definitions of the same
>   name in another component.

`man 5 elf`:

> **`STV_DEFAULT`**: Default symbol visibility rules. 
>   Globa and weak symbols are available to other
>   modules; references in the local module can
>   be interposed by definitions in other
>   modules.

About the [SysV ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf#page=92):

> When resolving symbolic references, the
>   dynamic linker examines the symbol tables with a breadth-first search.
>   That is, it first looks at the symbol table of the executable
>   program itself, then at the symbol tables of the
>   `DT_NEEDED` entries (in order), then at the second level DT_`NEEDED`
>   entries, and so on.

If that's not what's expected, using `STV_HIDDEN` on the symbol prevents it from behind visible outside of the shared object.

In contrast, on Windows a symbol is always imported from a given DLL and the symbols are not exported to other DLLs by default anyway.