# How to use global variables across projects in a solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a C++ solution in which there is a global variable which I want to be accessible across projects in the solution file. I know this is not recommended but what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Define the variable once, in the file that originally has the global variable and declare the variable `extern` in every file that uses it.

File 1:

```
int GlobalVariable;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // blablabla
}
```

File 2:

```
extern int GlobalVariable;

int somefunc(void) {
    // blablabla
}
```

File 3:

```
extern int GlobalVariable;

// blablabla
```

Comment: @nightcrawler: So I make the variable global in one and use extern in other files?

Comment: Bruce: Second, example. And it's nightcracker, not crawler :)

Comment: I get a LINKER error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol in the file in the project where I use extern. Within the same project I don't get this error. Say Project 1(File 1.cpp, File 2.cpp) and Project 2 (File 3.cpp). I get error in File 3.cpp.

Comment: @nightcracker:: Shouldn't there be a difference between Translation Unit and Project??

Comment: @nightcracker: I created a sample solution file and using extern works there. Why do I get an error in my actual solution?

Comment: Separate projects are separate projects. File 1 is not part of Project 2, so the GlobalVariable does not exist in that project. Please make sure you understand the difference between definitions and declarations. :) What exactly are you trying to accomplish, anyway?

Comment: @Karl: I am trying to log the exit from all function calls. I want to use a global ofstream for this.

Answer (score 2):

All projects in a solution - ie you're building several dlls, grouped togetehr in a solution?

If that's the case then you have the problem that the a global in one dll cannot easily be read by another dll. You will need write the global to shared memory and have all dlls read from there.

An alternative aproach is easy: create a dll jsut to hold your shared variables and wrap them in a pragma. eg from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
#pragma data_seg (".myseg")
   int i = 0; 
   char a[32]n = "hello world";
#pragma data_seg()
```

then each of your different dlls can link with the 'data dll', the data dll will contain a single instance of the variables no matter how many times its loaded or in which process. Performance counters use this technique to quickly pass data counters between the process that generates the data and perfmon.exe that reads and displays it.

Comment: "you're building several dlls, grouped together in a solution" - Yes. How do I make others link with this "data dll". Do I still need to use extern in order to access the global variable?

Comment: @gbjbaand: I created a new dll project and wrote the data section and it compiled successfully. How do I use the variable now in cpp files of other project. Do I add the dll as a reference? Please help

Comment: "add as a reference"? Oh. In unmanaged code you'd just link both apps with the same dll and that variable would be present in both, and contain the same data. I don't think you're going to be able to use the same technique in .net - you'll have to look at interprocess communication (IPC) techniques instead for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Translation Unit and Project (specifically in Visual Studio).

In C and C++ you can make a global variable only accessible from the file in which it's declared by using the static keyword in front of the declaration. Globals that don't use the static keyword are accessible from any C or C++ file compiled into the program.

But frankly your question is not clear. When you say `Global` there can be lots of perspectives to it, as Wikipedia says in the article on [Global Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable):

*The C language does not use the term global, though in a small program contained in a single file it is possible to get the same effect by declaring a variable outside all functions (see below). However, such a variable should be called external, not global, since its scope is limited to the single file.*

But, you may go through these links to see if you can solve the your specific problem:

[Global variables/functions across different projects](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1150862&page=56)

[Shared global variable in C++ static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186926/shared-global-variable-in-c-static-library)

[How to implement process-global variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669989/how-to-implement-process-global-variable-in-c)